# how can I avoid column which contain null or zero value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to avoid those column  which contain null or zero value

### here the table structure

### -- Table structure for table `orders`

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `restaurant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_method` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `total_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `orders`
--

INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `customer_id`, `restaurant_id`, `source_id`, `purchase_method`, `total_price`, `date_created`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 3, 'Cash', 500, '2016-05-31 11:44:16'),
(2, 1, 1, 3, 'Cash', 1500, '2016-06-01 11:44:22'),
(3, 1, 1, 3, '', 650, '2016-06-02 11:44:26'),
(4, 1, 1, 2, 'cash', 1500, '2016-06-03 11:44:31'),
(5, 1, 1, 1, 'cash', 12000, '2016-06-04 21:08:00'),
(6, 1, 1, 1, 'cash', 14500, '2016-06-05 00:00:00'),
(7, 1, 1, 2, 'cash', 15000, '2016-06-10 09:47:15'),
(8, 1, 1, 2, 'cash', 14500, '2016-05-10 10:03:55'),
(9, 1, 1, 1, 'cash', 11800, '2016-06-08 00:00:00'),
(10, 1, 1, 2, 'ss', 300, '2016-06-08 01:06:56'),
(11, 1, 1, 1, 'online', 400, '2016-05-10 10:03:20'),
(12, 1, 1, 3, 'cash', 5000, '2016-06-09 06:23:16'),
(13, 1, 1, 2, 'cash', 2000, '2016-05-10 10:03:35'),
(14, 1, 1, 1, 'cash', 499, '2016-04-11 18:30:00'),
(15, 1, 1, 1, 'cash', 2010, '2016-03-11 18:58:00'),
(16, 1, 1, 1, 'cash', 599, '2016-03-11 18:30:00'),
(17, 1, 1, 1, 'online', 699, '2016-05-02 18:30:00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

the query I tried below it


SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=1 THEN (total_price) END) Jan,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=2 THEN (total_price) END) Feb,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=3 THEN (total_price) END) Mar,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=4 THEN (total_price) END)  Apr,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=5 THEN (total_price) END) May,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=6 THEN (total_price) END) Jun,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=7 THEN (total_price) END)  July,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=8 THEN (total_price) END) Aug,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=9 THEN (total_price) END) Sep,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=10 THEN (total_price) END) 'Oct',
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=11 THEN (total_price) END) Nov,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date_created)=12 THEN (total_price) END) 'Dec'
FROM orders
WHERE source_id =1 AND  date_created BETWEEN(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND CURDATE()
```

Result I get from query

```
Jan    Feb  Mar  Apr    May   Jun   July    Aug  Sep    Oct  Nov   Dec
null   null null null   null  38300 null null null null null null  null
```

desire result

```
 may june 
 0    38300
```

Answer (score 3):

A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns, determined by the `from` clause.  If you want a variable set of columns, then you can use dynamic SQL.

In your case, perhaps getting the results as columns would suffice:

```
select month(date_created), sum(total_price)
from orders
where source_id = 1 and
      date_created BETWEEN(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and CURDATE()
group by month(date_created)
having sum(total_price) <> 0;
```